# Getting value from query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having problems with getting a value from a single column call.

```
select sum(price) as testPrice from sales where quantity > 10
```

but when I inspect the resultset, I get the following,

```
[#"5"}>]
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very strange result. I am curious why you are not writing the query using ActiveRecord methods:

```
@testPrice = Sale.sum(:price, :conditions => "quantity > 10")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Just been having problems with ActiveRecord, sigh ahah, but thank you again

Comment: yeah, it did. Is there any good API you know about, something like noobkit.com(that used to work)

Comment: Not that I have found. I just use http://api.rubyonrails.org but you have to really know what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh, and be sure to mark the question as "accepted" for future searchers. And welcome to Stack Overflow!